# _satellite.Logger.getHistory() is there similar command for adobe launch?

Tags: adobe

I need to see all rules fired on the page. Earlier I was using  "_satellite.Logger.getHistory()" from console to get all rules but it doesn't seem working anymore with Adobe Launch product. Appreciate your help.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2473084

thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

No, but an API is available to collect similar information. See https://medium.com/launch-by-adobe/launch-library-monitoring-hooks-8495dd91b57. Note that these APIs are for debugging purposes only; you shouldn't use them in production code.